# How to store huge integers in java?

Tags: java, math

How to store hug number in java where overflow has occured like the factorial of 99999 and higher numbers
I have used long datatype but it didn't work

Comment: [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). But if you want to store 99999!, you are probably Doing It Wrong.

Comment: It's a part of a calculation not the final result

Comment: You do realize that 99999! has about 450,000 digits when expressed in base 10, don't you?

Comment: It's a test case of a program so I am working on it now. But I think BigInteger will work as @Tunaki said

Comment: Can the formula be modified so it doesn't require calculating such huge factorials? If the final result is a "reasonable" number then there should be room for optimization at the math level.

Comment: I doubt that anyone needs 99999!.  I agree with Tunaki: You're doing it wrong.  Permutations and combinations involve ratios of factorials that have beaucoup cancellations.  No Taylor series needs that many terms.

Comment: That's right I tried making cancellation and it worked but now I am facing a different problem
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

[java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

> Immutable arbitrary-precision integers. All operations behave as if BigIntegers were represented in two's-complement notation (like Java's primitive integer types). BigInteger provides analogues to all of Java's primitive integer operators, and all relevant methods from java.lang.Math. Additionally, BigInteger provides operations for modular arithmetic, GCD calculation, primality testing, prime generation, bit manipulation, and a few other miscellaneous operations.